# Coloured reference in caption

Tags: cross-referencing, color, captions

I am using bibliographic references in my figures and the caption is coloured. However, the reference is always black (see image).
[image]

This is the code I'm using for colouring the captions

```
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{54,95,145}    
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font={color=blue1}]{caption}
```

I'm also using hyperref so I can click the links when I use a reference but I don't want them to be blue in the text, only in the captions.

```
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[figure,table]{hypcap}
\hypersetup
{
    bookmarksnumbered,
    pdfstartview={FitH},
    citecolor={black},
    linkcolor={black},
    urlcolor={black}
    pdfpagemode={UseOutlines}
}
```

Any idea how to make references blue only in the captions?

Comment: Instead of manually changing the font color of cites, links, references, ... to black, why not use the `hidelinks` option? This will give you a blue colored link in teh caption while links in the text will be colored black. However, please note that this will hide all types of references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could define a new caption font option called "hypercolor" which sets the color of hyperlinks in captions. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{54,95,145}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup
{
    bookmarksnumbered,
    pdfstartview={FitH},
    citecolor={black},
    linkcolor={black},
    urlcolor={black}
    pdfpagemode={UseOutlines}
}

\usepackage{caption}

% Declare caption font "hypercolor" which sets the color of the hyper links
\DeclareCaptionFont{hypercolor}{%
  \hypersetup{%
    citecolor={#1},%
    linkcolor={#1},%
    urlcolor={#1}%
  }%
}

% Use "blue1" as color for caption text and hyper links
\captionsetup{font={color=blue1,hypercolor=blue1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering A figure
\caption{A figure. \autoref{fig:whatever}}
\label{fig:whatever}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Of course one could use different colors for caption text and hyperlinks inside captions, too. For example:

```
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{54,95,145}
\definecolor{blue2}{RGB}{0,0,255}
...
\captionsetup{font={color=blue1,hypercolor=blue2}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works! :)

Comment: @user2574 What if you want to modify the color of only one link inside of the caption? I have tried to hypersetup inside of the caption but it throws an uninformative error